# Setting runes to skills

Tags: diablo-iii

When you level up and gain a new rune on a certain skill, if I were to go and activate that new rune, do I only get that perk set for that rune? Or do all other runes for that skill add their benefits, too?

If it's confusing what I am asking let me try explaining it this way...
Say rune #4 just gets unlocked for my skill, but I have been set on rune #2. If I go and activate rune #4, do runes 1-3 work in conjunction with it too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the rune you choose is the active rune, and you get only its benefits. So you need to **choose** between the different bonuses.

In your example, **only** rune #4 will give you benefits. Just as before you didn't get the bonuses from rune #1 and only from rune #2.

Many times runes collide. Logically you can't have a rune that increases the damage of the power together with a rune that causes several weaker shots of that power.

Comment: Not to mention every spell would be OP if you could apply every rune at once.

Comment: Diablo is all about being OP. Id like it if you could apply multiple runes at once somehow.

Comment: @Ender Well if Blizzard plans on implementing a PvP that is worth anything they better get their balancing straight haha.

Comment: @Ender, actually Diablo 3 is all about many different possibilities, according to Blizzard. So by letting you choose only 1 rune they open a very large field of different builds, while if it was the other way around, you would've get that all the people that chose a certain skill would just use the last rune.